# Set up tunnel for SVN (using Cornerstone/Mac)

Tags: macos, svn, cornerstone

I've been using Tortoise to checkout/commit to the svn repository. It is set up to use Tortoiseplink as SSH client (D:\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe -l foo -pw bar). I have now moved to a Mac (using Cornerstone) but I can't get the same sort of setup. Whatever I do, I can't get Cornerstone to connect to the repo.

Do I need to set up an ssh tunnel? And how do I do that on a Mac?

Update: screenshot of the settings needed

[image: Cornerstone settings]

Answer (score 1):

What you have looks correct - the only thing I can think of is that your SSH connection is not working for some reason. Have you tried just doing an SSH to the server hosting the repository? To do this, open Terminal and type:

```
$ ssh hostgator_username@gator123.hostgator.com
```

If you are prompted for a password and you can log into the machine then that is a good start - if not that suggests that something is fishy with your network setup.